# What is the difference between general and common?

Tags: vocabulary

Can I completely use them as synonym of each other?

For the example:

> People generally sleep in the night.

and

> People commonly sleep in the night.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In many contexts, *generally* and *commonly* are synonymous.

Indeed, if we look them up on thesaurus.com, we'll see that each is listed as the second synonym of the other.

- http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/generally
- http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/commonly

The possible difference in meaning is well-indicated by each one's first synonym.

The first synonym listed for *generally* is *broadly*. That means that *generally* can be used to talk about how most people behave. (Or how most frogs smell, or how most bowls look, or whatever.)

You could say that people *generally* are born, live, and die. That's an incredible simplification of life, but it nevertheless describes the overall process. You couldn't substitute *commonly* there because there's no group of people who don't follow that pattern.

*Commonly*, on the other hand, can describe something that happens *frequently* (its first synonym) but which doesn't necessarily happen to most people. You could say people *commonly* die in car accidents. A billion or more people hop in a car without dying every day, so we can't say that people *generally* die in car accidents, but fatal accidents are nevertheless a normal enough occurrence that we wouldn't describe a traffic fatality as uncommon.

(There may be some semantics at play there depending on what you're trying to emphasize – for example, you may say car accidents *are* uncommon if you're trying to emphasize the safety of traveling by car over traveling by rocket-propelled skateboard or something – but the basic contrast between normalcy and frequency is what matters here.)